# magento 2 How to override module-configurable-product configurable.js file

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I want to override following js core file.

`public_html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend`

I have tried in my custom theme as follow but it is not working

`public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js`

i have also created required `requirejs-config.js` and added following code

/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make sure, that your module has `Magento_ConfigurableProduct` in sequence in `module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then add `requirejs-config.js` file in view/frontend directory with code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Vendor_ModuleName/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

Finally add `configurable.js` file in view/frontend/web/js directory with:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
], function($){

    $.widget('silvan.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {
        //code you want to override
    });

    return $.silvan.configurable;
});
```

Run this Commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: This worked for me in M2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Need to run :

rm -rf var/generation/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/_requirejs/ var/cache var/di var/page_cache pub/static/_cache

./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override at theme level then don't need anything.
Donot require `requirejs-config.js` at `app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/requirejs-config.js`

Just put `configurable.js` at 
`app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js`.Means  file name should same with core file and  same location.

After that do Static content deploy.It must required.